# Accept $L=\{ww^r:w\in\Sigma^*\}$ in less that $|w|$ storage

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Suppose $L=\{ww^r:w\in\Sigma^*\}$. Already, we know that we can draw a PDA for $L$ such that accept each $w\in L$ with space complexity at least $|w|$.

My question is how is it possible to draw a PDA that accepts or rejects $w$ with space complexity $\frac{w}{C}$ for some constant $C$? Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Just one thing comes to my mind, maybe it's possible to partition $w$ into  $\frac{w}{C}$ parts but at this I get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is (obviously) possible if $|\Sigma| = 1$ or $C = 1$.

It is also possible for $|\Sigma| > 1$ and $C>1$. The idea is that you can use a bigger stack alphabet to encode multiple letters at once.

For example, if $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$, the following PDA recognizes $L$, and the stack is at most $\frac{|w|}2$ for an input $w$. Here, $\Gamma = \{Z_0, A, B, C, D, E, F\}$, and $X$ designates any stack symbol.

[image]

The idea is that stack symbols $C$, $D$, $E$ and $F$ represent $aa$, $ab$, $ba$ and $bb$ respectively.